# How do I calculate a combined data error?

Tags: statistics, average

I have a time series of data points read from an instrument, I also get an estimate of the error ($\sigma$) for each of these readings.
e.g.

$10.12  \pm 0.05$

$10.09  \pm 0.02$

$10.20  \pm 0.12$
etc.

To reduce the noise inherent in the data I'm binning (averaging) them with respect to time intervals, all fine and simple even with my basic maths knowledge. But what is the correct way of combining the errors readings?

Comment: Just to clarify are you asking how to calculate bounds for the (mean) average of those numbers?

Comment: I want to know the "standard" mathematical way (if there is one) to combine the errors. Should I just average them, take RMS or some other method.

Comment: It rather depends on whether you think the real errors (measurement - true value) are independent of each other

Comment: I think errors are independent of each other as they are mainly due to standard Gaussian distribution effects in the actual signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself in the end on Wikipedia under [weighted arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean)
I've also used a weighted mean instead of a simple mean using the reciprocal of sigma squared as the weighting factor for each value.

Answer (score 1):

I will show two calcultions.

Example:  w = (4.52 ± 0.02) cm, x = ( 2.0 ± 0.2) cm, y = (3.0 ± 0.6) cm. Find z = x + y - w and its uncertainty.

z = x + y - w = 2.0 + 3.0 - 4.5 = 0.5 cm

METHOD 1

Delta z = Delta x + Delta y + Delta w = 0.2 + 0.6 + 0.02 = 0.82  rounding to  0.8 cm

So z = (0.5 ± 0.8) cm

METHOD 2

Solution with standard deviations

Delta z = SQRT((Delta x)^2 + (Delta y)^2 + (Delta w)^2)

Delta z = 0.633 cm

z = (0.5 ± 0.6) cm

Notice that we round the uncertainty to one significant figure and round the answer to match.

Now you can apply this to your measurements.

Comment: Can you show the general case where the number of samples is variable? In my data sometimes I will have only one sample (obviously not a problem) but other times I may have 100+ samples or anywhere in between.

Comment: Use what explained in point c of this link http://www.rit.edu/~w-uphysi/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart1.html

Comment: The link shows how to calculate the uncertainty of a set of readings not how to combine a set of uncertainties.

Comment: It also does not give any indication as to what z = x + y - w is nor its general case (more than three reading).